# Can you make a field unique in a content type?

Tags: 8

I have an *Employee* content type with an *ID* field.

Can I make the field unique, so that Drupal would prevent me from entering the same *ID* more than once by mistake?

Comment: Not out of the box, you'll need custom coding for this.

Comment: You might use the UUID https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/unique_field_ajax might do the trick as well.

Comment: Since the question is about Drupal 8, there is no need to use the *Universally Unique IDentifier* module. Drupal 8 entities already have a UUID.

Comment: Try https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation

Answer (score 5):

You can add a validation constraint to your field.
There is two ways to do that:

1. Setting a validation constraint to a field you haven't defined by implementing [`hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter/8.2.x):

```
function YOURMODULE_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'ENTITY_TYPE' && $bundle === 'BUNDLE_NAME') {
    if (isset($fields['FIELD_NAME'])) {
      $fields['FIELD_NAME']->addConstraint('UniqueField');
    }
  }
}
```

2. Setting a validation constraint to a field you have defined in [baseFieldDefinitions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3AbaseFieldDefinitions/8.8.x)

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entityType) {
 $fields['FIELD_NAME'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
   ->setLabel(t('MY UNIQUE FIELD'))
   ->addConstraint('UniqueField');

 return $fields;
}
```

If you want to create your own validation constraint you can check [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint).

Comment: It is maybe worth noting that UniqueField will check uniqueness across all nodes (or whatever entity type you are using). So eg if you have a Rank field in two content types, there can be only one Rank #1.

Answer (score -2):

A core Drupal way to achieve your result:

1. Create Taxonomy "Employee ID".
2. Add Taxonomy reference field to "Employee" content type.
3. Ensure to check "Create referenced entities if they don't already exist" in field settings.

You will know if the ID exists if the term can be referenced. Plus this data becomes easily reusable.